# javascript button doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I can't find my mistake to get the 2 minute / 5 minute buttons to work. I was able to locate several mistakes but when I went to test nothing changed. I'm not getting any errors so I'm having some trouble and thought someone would be able to assist.

The issue I assume is around line 10-33 of the Javascript. However, I'm including all 3 (html, js, css) for testing purposes.

```js
const app = () => {
  const song = document.querySelector('.song');
  const play = document.querySelector('.play');
  const outline = document.querySelector('.moving-outline circle');
  const video = document.querySelector('.vid-container video');

  //sounds
  const sounds = document.querySelectorAll('.sound-picker button');
  //time display = h3 - html
  const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('.time-display');
  const timeselect = document.querySelectorAll('.time-select button');
  //Get the length of the outline
  const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
  //Duration
  let fakeDuration = 600;

  outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength;
  outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;

  //Play Sound
  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkPlaying(song);
  });

  //Select sound
  timeselect.forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener('click', function() {
      fakeDuration = this.getattribute("data-time");
      timeDisplay.textContent = `${Math.floor(fakeDuration / 60)}:${Math.floor(
        fakeDuration % 60
        )}`;
    });
  });

  // A function to stop and play the sounds
  const checkPlaying = song => {
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      video.play();
      play.src = './svg/pause.svg';
    } else {
      song.pause();
      video.pause();
      play.src = './svg/play.svg';
    }
  };

  // Animate the circle
  song.ontimeupdate = () => {
    let currentTime = song.currentTime;
    let elapsed = fakeDuration - currentTime;
    let seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);
    let minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);

    //Animate the circle
    let progress = outlineLength - (currentTime / fakeDuration) * outlineLength;
    outline.style.strokeDashoffset = progress;
    //Animate the text
    timeDisplay.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  };
};

app();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.time-select,
.sound-picker,
.player-container {
  height: 80%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.player-container {
  position: relative;
}

.player-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.time-display {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}

.time-select button,
.sound-picker button {
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.time-select button:hover {
  color: black;
  background: White;
}

.sound-picker button {
  border: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.sound-picker button:nth-child(1) {
  background: #4972a1
}

.sound-picker button:nth-child(2) {
  background: #a14f49;
}

.sound-picker button img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"></link>
  <title> Meditation App </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">

    <div class="vid-container">
      <video loop>
                <source src="./video/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
    </div>

    <div class="time-select">
      <button data-time="120"> 2 minutes</button>
      <button data-time="300"> 5 minutes</button>
      <button data-time="600"> 10 minutes</button>
    </div>
    <div class="player-container">
      <audio class="song">
                <source src="./sounds/rain.mp3"/>
            </audio>
      <img src="./svg/play.svg" alt="Play" class="play">
      <svg class="track-outline" width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          
        <circle
            cx="226.5" 
            cy="226.5" 
            r="216.5" 
            stroke="white" 
            stroke-width="20"
            />
        </svg>
      <svg class="moving-outline" width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
        
        <circle 
            cx="226.5" 
            cy="226.5" 
            r="216.5" 
            stroke="#018EBA" 
            stroke-width="20"
            />
        </svg>
      <h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="sound-picker">
      <button data-sound="./sounds/rain.mp3" data-video="./video/rain.mp4">
                <img src="./svg/rain.svg" alt="rain">
            </button>
      <button data-sound="./sounds/beach.mp3" data-video="./video/beach.mp4">
                <img src="./svg/beach.svg" alt="beach"/>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As always any and all assistance is appreciated.

Left mouse click on both the 2 and 5 minute countdown don't work. I tried both before and after clicking play button. Located several "issues" but none that affected the code from running/ gave the expected desire with the 2/5 minute buttons.

Comment: Have you already checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: "*issue I assume is around line 10-33 of the Javascript*" - note: we can't see your lines of code in this code snippet

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I checked the console on VS. I didn't check the console on the browser. New to html/css/js does the browser tend to have more insight than the IDE?

Comment: @Aleksandar wait so even when you click to run code snippet it doesn't show line numbers? I wasn't aware. does that mean instead of noting the line I should note the section I assume is the issue; moving forward when I post?

Comment: No worries @navi, most of the time the snippets we post here are small enough to literally quote the lines in question. Good job on nicely reducing and formatting your code for this question!

Comment: @navi yes you could mention a variable or function name so that people can jump to check out that function instead of manually counting lines themselves. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have error here

```
fakeDuration = this.getattribute("data-time");
```

you should make 'a' capital letter, like this:

```
fakeDuration = this.getAttribute("data-time");
```

Comment:  I swear I went up and down editing things like capital letters before posting because I noticed when i did Math.floor it didn't auto capitalize. I'll definitely be more attentive of Capitalization. I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Or better yet, don't use this function at all and instead use `this.dataset.time`. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: it is annoying too find the error is as simple as that , they should make extensions in VS code to check out those things tho.